# How can I copy a case class with its trait?

Tags: scala, case-class

I have the following:

```scala
scala> trait Tail
scala> case class Cat(name: String)
scala> val aa = new Cat(name = "bob")
val aa: Cat with Tail = Cat(ben)
scala> val bb = aa.copy(name = "ted")
val bb: Cat = Cat(ted)
```

Why is it that `bb` didn't inherited the `Tail` trait?

How can I copy `aa` and still preserve the trait?

Comment: case classes' copy method is not virtual and is not subject to type hierarchy lookup. Its parameters and return type is set.

Answer (score 1):

> `val aa: Cat with Tail = Cat(ben)`

Given the line above, this shouldn't happen. I assume you instead had

> `scala> val aa = new Cat(name = "ben") with Tail`

In this case, it inherits `copy` from `Cat`, and the definition is given [in Scala Language Specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes). Following it, you can see that `aa.copy("ted")` just calls the constructor and returns `new Cat("ted")`.

If you want to return `Cat with Tail`, you could implement it manually:

```
val aa = new Cat(name = "ben") with Tail {
  override def copy(name: String): Cat with Tail = new Cat(name) with Tail
}
```

or declare a separate class, but there's no built-in support. If you made the subclass a case class, it would get its own `copy` method, but a case class can't extend a case class; so in that case, `Cat` shouldn't be a case class.